# Array input for an ODEINT function in SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I am trying to pass an array into an ODE and then solve that ODE using the ODEINT function. However, I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: The size of the array returned by func (50) does not match the size of y0 (1)

Here is my sample code:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#First ODE
def eq1 (x,t):
    return (0.5*(x)+2*x**2)

#Second ODE
def eq2 (y,t,m):
    p = np.sqrt(y)+m*y**2
    return p

t = np.linspace(0,1,50)
IC = [2] # Initial Condition
m = [0.1]*len(t) # A random variable

#Solver for the first ODE
one = odeint(eq1,IC,t) 
plt.plot (t,one)

#Solver for the Second ODE
two = odeint (eq2,IC,t,(m,))
plt.plot (t,two)
```

The first solver works fine, but the second one throws an error. Based on the error message, I understand that the dimension of the IC is not same as that of the variable m. Hence, if I comment out the lines related to the solver of the first ODE and change IC as `IC = [2]*len(m)`, the error message goes away. How3ever, `two.shape` is (50,50). I do not know which dimension of the solution (two) is the actual answer.

I would really appreciate some guidance.
Thank You!

Comment: Please explain the mathematical differential equation that you are trying to solve.  I suspect you have not translated it correctly into python code.  In particular, what does `m` represent in `eq2()`?  You made `m` a sequence with length `len(t)` containing only the value 0.1, but a comment says "a random variable".  In what sense do you mean "random"?

Comment: Both equations are completely arbitrary - I made up the equations. I just wanted to find out how to implement ODEINT when one of the variables is an array. For exp., 'm' could be sinusoidal signal representing pulsatile capillary blood flow - instead of an array containing only the value 0.1. I think I meant to say, "an arbitrary signal" instead of "random variable" - I used a wrong word.

Comment: *"For exp., 'm' could be sinusoidal signal representing pulsatile capillary blood flow"*  In that case, `m` should be a function of time `t`, not an array.  Then your code in `eq2` would be something like `p = np.sqrt(y) + m(t)*y**2`, and you would define `m(t)` (a function that returns a scalar) elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way to pass an array as a parameter for an ODE function in Python. Funnily enough I think it's possible in Matlab. The only way to solve your problem (but inefficiently) is to use a FOR loop.